# Цепочка прототипов и hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять. На MDN пишут, что:

> Длительное время поиска свойств, располагающихся относительно высоко в цепочке прототипов, может негативно сказаться на производительности (performance), особенно в критических в этом смысле местах кода. Кроме того, попытка найти несуществующие свойства неизбежно приведёт к проверке на их наличие у всех объектов цепочки прототипов.
>
> hasOwnProperty — единственная существующая в JavaScript возможность работать со свойствами, не затрагивая цепочку прототипов.

Но ведь hasOwnProperty наследуемый метод, причем от Object.prototype, а значит при вызове происходит его поиск по всей цепочке, до Object.prototype от которого он наследуется. Или что-то я не пойму?

Какая разница, искать свойство без hasOwnProperty, и тем самым, есть вероятность долгого прохода через всю цепочку прототипов. Или с hasOwnProperty, и в таком случает обязательно проходить через всю цепочку, чтобы воспользоваться им, а уже с помощью него искать только собственное свойство объекта. Объясните пожалуйста какой профит со стороны производительности?

[Ссылка на статью < < <](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: А как, например, вы проверите такое свойство `{ prop: null }`(без hasOwnProperty)?

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg Например с помощью оператора in

Comment: Оператор `in` найдет во всей цепочке, а если необходимо только  в самом объекте. Вот тут вам и понадобиться hasOwnProperty. Или если обойти свойства объекта `arr=Object.keys( {...} );`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg но проверить свойство можно через in, а Вы это и спрашивали. В остальном Вы правы, но я об этом не спрашивал.

Comment: Да просто вы спрашивали "Какая разница без или с hasOwnProperty". Я и привел простейший пример где это используется и других способов видимо и нет.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg правил немного вопрос.

Comment: Ну, собственно, поэтому `hasOwnProperty` стараются не использовать. Из-за его тяжеловесности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теоретически — если представить себе случай с очень длинной цепочкой прототипов, в котором крайне критична производительность, то можно делать так:

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'prop')) {
    // obj имеет собственное свойство prop
}
```

Такой вызов метода hasOwnProperty не будет проходить по цепочке прототипов obj.

Практически же заниматься подобными микрооптимизациями нет никакого резона до тех пор, пока нет данных профилирования, явно указывающих, что проблема в этом. В целом современные движки хорошо оптимизируют поиск по цепочке прототипов (т. к. это очень критично для производительности JS).